# Checkstyle report doesn't show images

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I added Checkstyle to my Maven project and it's generating the report, but with broken image/style links. `target/site/images/` only contains rss.png. How can I make it generate the report properly with images?

Here is the relevant part from my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
```

I am running maven with `jxr:jxr checkstyle:checkstyle` via IntelliJ. I also tried different configuration files (checkstyle.xml) from different sources.

Comment: Can you show `checkstyle.xml`?

Comment: checkstyle.xml: http://pastebin.com/hZmkD6XH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate the site with `mvn site` instead of `checkstyle:checkstyle` to have the styles generated. See also here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-127